# How to build targets without including directories into each other compiling command?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I have multiple targets in one project, also sub projects.

On the top of CMakeLists.txt there are includes for necessary folders:

```
include_directories(8021QBG)
include_directories(8021x)

#sub project
add_subdirectory(test)
```

Then I have description of building command. They are pretty same for all libraries:

```
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES
        8021QBG/*.h
        8021QBG/*.cpp
        )
add_library(8021qbg SHARED
        ${SOURCE_FILES}
        )
set_target_properties(8021qbg PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_CUSTOM "-lxml2 -lm")
set_target_properties(8021qbg PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS " ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_CUSTOM} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_COMMON}")
```

But when I build project, no matter what library I see the same beginning:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -g -fPIC -I/home/user/cmake_libs/8021QBG -I/home/user/cmake_libs/8021x
```

But 8021QBG and 8021x - different libraries.

It includes all directories into every compile command.

How to split up included directories by each library?

```
/usr/bin/g++ -g -fPIC -I/home/user/cmake_libs/8021QBG
```

and separately

```
/usr/bin/g++ -g -fPIC -I/home/user/cmake_libs/8021x
```

Comment: The `COMPILE_FLAGS` property is for ***compiler*** flags, not to add linker libraries (which you usually do with the [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html): `target_link_libraries(8021qbg xml2 m)`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes, thank you about this, I will fix it. What about splitting up includes? Can you help me?

Comment: Perhaps use [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html#command:target_include_directories) instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I added to my test sub project this command ```target_include_directories(test PRIVATE coding/variable_field coding/packet coding/utils )``` and after rebuild I still see other includes for this 'test' target

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Or I should remove ```command include_directories``` at all?

Comment: Yes, `include_directories` sets for *all* targets globally.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I understand, cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to build two different targets you with two different includes i suggest this:

Follow this [Ref](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html)
With this you can create a target for each of your libs.

If your include the both libraries on the same target you'll get both includes in the same build command line.

Comment: I added to my test sub project this command
```target_include_directories(test PRIVATE
          coding/variable_field
          coding/packet
          coding/utils
)```
and after rebuild I still see other includes for this 'test' target

Comment: you should remove the command include_directories. This command includes in Project that directories, and when you build any target inside this project it will include that list of directories. In your case you should include per target.